# I am not connecting to internet, do I still need the windows firewall on?

Tags: windows, firewalls

Forgive my ignorance but I am truly uncertain.

Here is my situation:

I have dual booted a Linux distro and Windows 7 on my machine. Windows 7 sole purpose is for gaming, that's all. I'm not planning to get Windows Update nor game patches neither. Network adapters are disabled too. Should I let Windows Firewall ON?

I'll be happy if I can save some processing power when the firewall is off or I'm just over thinking?

Comment: After 5 years I have arrived to my conclusion that disabling your firewall is a bad idea because it's a bad practice and when you're picking up bad practices it can become a bad habit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firewalls generally operate at the network layer, if you have no network (you state the network adapters are disabled) there is nothing for the firewall to do, therefore, from a security perspective, turning off the firewall isn't going to be an issue.

Obviously this only holds true while the network adapters are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

**You are just overthinking.**

Firewall is not needed if you computer is not connected to the internet. If you are playing multiplayer games, and you need to connect to the internet, you might encounter some problems if you enable the firewall. However, Leaving the firewall off for the sake of gaming might be a bad idea.

Comment: Agreed that a firewall has very little use if the computer is not connected to the internet and adapters are disabled. However stating that the OP should leave his firewall off when connecting to the internet just for the sake of gaming is a bad idea.

Comment: I never said that he has to leave his firewall off. I just informed him that firewall might cause issues with some multiplayer games. Edited the answer anyway. @Joe

Comment: Thanks friend, I am now certain to disable my firewall and also I won't play multiplayer or online games as well.